# Convert type of column in Tableau desktop

Tags: tableau-api, desktop

Im using TALEAU DESKTOP for visualisation..
I have to change a type of my field in Data pane.

Tableau desktop set it by default to String but i want to change it to float ..
When i change it to float,all this column is NULL.

Have you any idea how to do please.

Comment: what values does the column hold? need about the values but not datatype of the column

Comment: all my values are float with values 2.1, or 3.0, or 1.0..

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: im using excel file

Comment: it works now !! i just deleted the fields and reloaded! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ensure that the data in the column contains numeric or float values. If it has string or non numeric values then Tableau will only make it Null since there is no equivalent float value.